# Pass an array to a middleware in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware

I got this handle in a middleware called rolMiddleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $roles)
{
    //dd($request->user());
    foreach ($roles as $rol) {
        if ($request->user()->getTipoUsuario($request->user()->tipo_usuario_id)->getNombreTipoUsuario() == $rol) {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
    abort(403, "¡No hay autorizacion!");
}
```

But $roles is an array, here is the route where I use the middleware:

```
Route::get('/mid', ['middleware' => 'roles:super admin', function () {
    return "done";
}]);
```

and the error that gives me is:

```
ErrorException in RolMiddleware.php line 22:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

You may thing that I do not need an array because I am only using it in super admin, for that route I only need super admin, but there would be routes that can be for super admin and the admin of an area.

Answer (score 28):

In laravel , you can separate your parameters which you want to pass to middleware using comma `,` as follows:

```
Route::get('/mid', ['middleware' => 'roles:super,admin', function () {
//                                              ^ note this
    return "done";
}]);
```

note that, this won't send parameters as an array, so you can't loop over `$roles` unless you use your passed parameters as [ellipsis parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics) as follows :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles)
```

rather, you will need to use a single parameter for each role:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role1, $role2) // .... and so on
```

Comment: That ellipsis parameters is all I need. $roles becomes array. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/access', ['middleware' => 'hasroles:super,admin', function () {
}]);
```

> passing one parameter to check user have created permission in my
>   cause

```
Route::middleware('admin')->namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/home', 'MainController@getIndex')->name('admin.index')->middleware("hasrole:create");
```

**Middleware:**

> ***1.Using Parameters***

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $parm1, $parm2){}
```

> ***2.Using var-arg***

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $parm1, $parm2){}
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$parm1){}
```

**Two-way Middleware Use**

> ***1: Register routeMiddleware***

```
// Within App\Http\Kernel Class...
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'hasrole' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\HasRole::class,
```

**Using:**

```
Route::get('admin/profile', function () {
})->middleware('hasrole');
```

> ***2: Not Register in routeMiddleware***

**Using:**

```
use App\Http\Middleware\HasRole;

Route::get('admin/profile', function () {
    //
})->middleware(HasRole::class);
```

Answer (score 3):

Send parameter as string like as

```
Route::prefix('panel')->middleware('auth:admin|editor')->group(function (){
    Route::get('/', [SiteController::class, 'index'])->name('site.index');
}
```

Program in middleware to sense this string as array

```
if (in_array(Auth::user()->rule, explode('|', $access))) {
   return $next($request);
} else {
   return redirect()->route('site.denied');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode` function within `middleware` for converting `string` to `array`.

**Controller**:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('RoleCheck:admin|user')->except(['index', 'show']);
}
```

**Middleware**:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $roles)
{   
    $user = Auth::user();
    $roles = explode("|", $roles); // convert $roles to array
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        if ($user->hasRole($role))
            return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('login');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what your functions do, but you can try something like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $roles)
{
    if(is_array($roles)){
        //dd($request->user());
        foreach ($roles as $rol) {
            if ($request->user()->getTipoUsuario($request->user()->tipo_usuario_id)->getNombreTipoUsuario() == $rol) {
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
    }else{
        if($request->user()->getTipoUsuario($request->user()->tipo_usuario_id)->getNombreTipoUsuario() == $roles)
            return $next($request);
    }
    abort(403, "¡No hay autorizacion!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always have `return $next($request);` at the end of a middleware file... Some of these examples fail to do that.

Here's how your routes will be (web.php file):

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
Route::middleware('CheckRole:super-admin')->group(function () {
//super-admin only routes here
});

Route::middleware('CheckRole:user')->group(function () {
//user only routes here
});
});
```

To add more roles to the above code, just put `CheckRole:super-admin,user` you can keep going with commas for the specific group.

The middlewares below will automatically keep anyone without permission out of the areas specified above, and only when a user is logged in

Make sure to add the below middleware to:

```
App\Http\Kernel.php
```

Under
`protected $middlewareAliases = [`
Put the following line:

```
'CheckRole' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole::class,
```

Your middleware will be:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class CheckRole
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$roles): Response
    {
        if ($request->user()) {

            $userRole = Auth::user()->role->value('name');

            if (! in_array($userRole, $roles)) {
                
                abort(403, 'Your account permissions do not allow access to the requested page');

            }

        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

This assumes you only have 1 role for 1 user. If you have multiple roles for 1 user, that would be a different check in your middleware code

If you have multiple Roles for multiple Users, you can use this middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class CheckRole
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$roles): Response
    {
        if ($request->user()) {

            $userRoles = Auth::user()->roles
                ->pluck('name')
                ->toArray();

            if (! array_intersect($userRoles, $roles)) {
                
                abort(403, 'Your account permissions do not allow access to the requested page');

            }

        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```